# How can spring @Cacheable work in service level with a dao call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following code:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    @Cacheable("callDao")
    @Override
    public MyResultModel callDao(MyCondition condition) {
        System.out.println("call without cache");
        return myDao.call(condition);
    }

    @Cacheable("cacheTest")
    @Override
    public MyResultModel cacheTest(MyCondition condition) {
        System.out.println("call without cache");
        return new MyResultModel(someProperties);
    }
}
```

However, the `callDao` cache does not work since the method still calls the DB all the time. On the other hand, `cacheTest` does work properly. What is wrong with my `callDao` method?

Here is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisCacheManagerConfiguration configuration,
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(configuration.getDefaultExpiration());
    cacheManager.setUsePrefix(configuration.isUsePrefix());
    cacheManager.setLoadRemoteCachesOnStartup(configuration.isLoadRemoteCachesOnStartup());
    return cacheManager;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, String> stringRedisTemplate(
        @Qualifier("stringRedisSerializer") RedisSerializer<String> keySerializer,
        @Qualifier("stringRedisSerializer") RedisSerializer<String> valueSerializer,
        @Qualifier("stringRedisSerializer") RedisSerializer<String> hashKeySerializer,
        @Qualifier("stringRedisSerializer") RedisSerializer<String> hashValueSerializer,
        JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    StringRedisTemplate template = new StringRedisTemplate();
    template.setKeySerializer(keySerializer);
    template.setValueSerializer(valueSerializer);
    template.setHashKeySerializer(hashKeySerializer);
    template.setHashValueSerializer(hashValueSerializer);
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();

    return template;
}

@Bean(name = "stringRedisSerializer")
public StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer() {
    return new StringRedisSerializer();
}
```

I only configured `CacheManager` and `RedisTemplate`. I also added the `@EnableCaching` annotation.

Hear is MyCondition:

```
public class MyCondition implements Serializable {

    /** 
     * @since JDK 1.8
     */  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6262123870251938833L;

    private String guid;
    private Boolean isDelete;

    public String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    public Boolean getIsDelete() {
        return isDelete;
    }

    public void setIsDelete(Boolean isDelete) {
        this.isDelete = isDelete;
    }
}
```

Hear is how i call these method

```
@EnableCaching
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({ "com.mypackage" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer {
    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        MyService myService = ctx.getBean(MyService.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            MyCondition condition = new ConditionForRideCard();
            condition.setGuid("adsgsfdhgsfgfdghhsdfgfadf");
            myService.callDao(condition);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
            myService.cacheTest(condition);
            System.out.println("=======================================================");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

AND i get result like this:

```
call without cache
-------------------------------------------------------
call without cache
=======================================================
call without cache
-------------------------------------------------------
=======================================================
call without cache
-------------------------------------------------------
=======================================================
call without cache
-------------------------------------------------------
=======================================================
call without cache
-------------------------------------------------------
=======================================================
call without cache
-------------------------------------------------------
=======================================================
call without cache
-------------------------------------------------------
=======================================================
call without cache
-------------------------------------------------------
=======================================================
call without cache
-------------------------------------------------------
=======================================================
call without cache
-------------------------------------------------------
=======================================================
```

Comment: PS: I configure my cache with redis.

Comment: Could be something with your cache config. Do post that

Comment: thanks for help, my config is posted. @Dark

Comment: Can you show the code of `MyCondition`? Also, how do you call the `callDao` method? Do you call it from a different class/service or within the same service?

Comment: thanks for help, the code of MyCondition is posted.@g00glen00b

Comment: I call the callDao from the main method use context.getBean().  And the main method is in another class file.@g00glen00b

Comment: you are retrieving an interface of your service and the cache annotations are on your implementation. if a JDK proxy is created for your bean the cache annotations won't be exposed at all. Try to get your bean as `MyServiceImpl`

Comment: does not work. thanks anyway.@StephaneNicoll

Comment: implement `hashCode` and `equals` in your `MyCondition` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [StuPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44966313) pointed out (in his deleted answer, requires 10000 reputation to see) and [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965731/how-can-spring-cacheable-work-in-service-level-with-a-dao-call/44970659#comment76910374_44965731) in the comments, you need to implement both `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `MyCondition` class.

Spring's cache abstraction works by caching the result of the method call based on the arguments. In this case, you have only one argument (`MyCondition`). However, the generated key will use the `hashCode()` implementation of the parameters.

In your case, you didn't implement `equals()` nor `hashCode()`, so every time you create a new `MyCondition` object, it will have a different hashcode, and thus, Spring won't know that it has its result cached.

This doesn't explain why the `cacheTest()` method does work though. But I guess this is due to code we're not seeing right now (either you're using a different condition, or there's something else going on).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally fix my problem. The reason is, i modified mycondition in mybatis inteceptor. Then the redis key is changed. So the second call can not hit the cache.